# How to condense multiple for loops with different initial values

Tags: c++

In a function, I have several consecutive for loops with the same code but different initial values for the control variable. The initial values are obtained from inputs to the function. Ie,

```
void thisFunction( class A a){
  //some other code

  for (int i = a.x; i != 0; --i){
    code
  }

  for (int i = a.y; i != 0; --i){
    code
  }

  for (int i = a.z; i != 0; --i){
    code
  }

  //some other code
}
```

Is there any way to condense all the for loops into one loop so that when I make changes to the code within the loop, I won't have to change it for all three loops? An alternative is to write anotherFunction() with the initial values as input, but I need access to local variables in thisFunction().

```
  void anotherFunction(int in){
      for (int i = in; i != 0; --i){
        code
      }
  }
```

So is there another way to condense the loops?

Thank you.

Comment: That depends on what's done inside the loop. Can you provide more content?

Comment: OK, David's answer worked great. This is not for professional use, so I prefer a simple solution. Writing another anotherFunction() would be more tedious and I have several sets of these loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*EDIT: In most cases you should avoid doing this, and rather follow [MSalter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649789/c-how-to-condense-multiple-for-loops-with-different-initial-values/3649825#3649825). Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.*

I am not sure how good an idea this is, but without any more context, a simple solution could be:

```
int starts[3] = { a.x, a.y, a.z };
for ( int var = 0; var < 3; ++var ) {
   for ( int i = starts[var]; i != 0; --i ) {
      // code
   }
}
```

Note that the values of the conditions are obtained once at the beginning of the function, that means that if the object `a` changes throughout the first loop, that change will not be visible in the later control loops. If you need that, the solution can be modified to store pointers.

**EDIT**: There is a comment suggesting the use of the size of the array. I did not add that here not to modify, but anyway, a better way of getting the array size is:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int N>
inline unsigned int array_size( T (&)[N] ) {
   return N;
}
//...
for ( int var = 0; var < array_size(starts); ++i ) {
```

Comment: Even better, the second line could be `for (int var = 0; var < sizeof(starts)/sizeof(starts[0]); ++var)`.

Comment: @Oli, I prefer the templated (type safe) implementation of the size of the array. I avoided adding that here not to complicate the code, but I have updated the answer now.

Comment: That's some pretty funky template syntax I've never seen before!  I had no idea you could get the compiler to infer parameters (other than types) like that!

Comment: @Oli, it is a 'little' more complex, and does not produce a compile time function (can be made to produce it) but the compiler will most probably inline the value and it is safe as passing a pointer will be a compile time error. To make it a compile time constant: `template <typename T, int N> char (&array_size_fn( T(&)[N] ))[N]; #define array_size( array ) sizeof( array_size_fn(array) )`

Answer (score 9):

Your hunch is right - you'll have to refactor your code into a separate function. Local variables of `thisFunction` will become arguments to `anotherFunction`; often these will be passed by reference .

Answer (score 2):

Using lambda expressions, you could do this:

```
void thisFunction( class A a)
{ 
    //some other code 
    auto code = [&] (int i)  
    { 
        // your code here 
    }; 

    for (int i = a.x; i != 0; --i)   
        code(i); 
    for (int i = a.y; i != 0; --i)   
        code(i); 
    for (int i = a.z; i != 0; --i)   
        code(i); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for a C++0x solution not available in the previous standard, to demonstrate features of the languages and how they can improve readability...

Answer (score 1):

You can use macro

```
#define ITERATE(_IN)   \
{\
      for (int _I = (_IN); _I != 0; --_I){\
         code       \
      }\
}\
```

Then you have access to local variables, and you only have to manage one copy of the code.
So, your code becomes

```
void thisFunction( class A a){
  //some other code

  ITERATE(a.x)
  ITERATE(a.y)
  ITERATE(a.z)

  //some other code
}
```

This may become difficult to debug, so you have to make sure first that it works well, before you make a macro of your `code`

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The loops will all be running for different numbers of iterations, surely?

The best you can do is factor out as much of the internals as possible, for instance, into a function like you suggested.  Alternatively, have the loop outside the function.

To avoid passing in a load of variables independently, you could consider wrapping them in a class or struct.

**Update** On second thoughts, David Rodriguez's answer suggestion is a pretty good solution!